# How to add colspan to <td> If I am making a table which <tr>s are displaying vertically

Tags: html, css

Sorry for my poor english. I have little problem with colspan

tr tag's default display is table-row but in my table, items except th should be

displayed vertically. So I added display:inline-block to tr which contain

td and display:block to td.

and now, adding colspan to td doesn't work. Nothing changes

this is my jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/ffa7h0ub/1/

Codes for those who can't visit the link

```
            <section id="Groups">

            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th class="hidden"></th>
                    <th id="DiagonalLine"><span> Teams </span><span>Results</span></th>
                    <th>W</th>
                    <th>D</th>
                    <th>L</th>
                    <th>GF</th>
                    <th>GA</th>
                    <th>P</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="groups groupA">Group A</td>
                    <td class="groups groupB">Group B</td>
                    <td class="groups groupC">Group C</td>
                    <td class="groups groupD">Group D</td>
                    <td class="groups groupE">Group E</td>
                    <td class="groups groupF">Group F</td>
                    <td class="groups groupG">Group G</td>
                    <td class="groups groupH">Group H</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">Russia</td>
                    <td colspan="2">Saudi Arabia</td>
                    <td colspan="2">Egypt</td>
                    <td colspan="2">Uruguay</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Portugal</td>
                    <td>Spain</td>
                    <td>Morocco</td>
                    <td>Iran</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                </tr>
            </table>

        </section>
```

CSS:

```
section#Groups tr:not(:first-child){
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
}
section#Groups td{
  display:block;
}
 section#Groups th.hidden{
  width:40px;
}
section#Groups th{
 display:inline-block;
}
```

Tried change display:block to display:table-row but didn't work.

Comment: Can you explain why you want to use a table in your HTML, but yet not display your data in normal tabular form? Because what you are trying to do would be much easier if you just don't use tables, unless there is some underlying reason why you have to use them.

Comment: @ecg8 because If you google world cup group tables, all teams and groups have a vertical layout(?) and they are on left side. Status is on the top and right side and have a horizontal layout. http://www.fifa.com/worldcup/groups/index.html check this link. Second reason is I thought it will be much easier with JQuery animation. Later, I will add css display:none to some tr by adding class.

Comment: @ecg8  The most important thing for me is layout. Div or table or something other doesn't matter. I chose this way because I thought it is the most easiest way. No much CSS is needed

Comment: If you override the default layout of tables, don't expect things like colspan to work correctly. I suggest you rethink how your layout should be structured. If it doesn't conform to normal table structure, don't use HTML tables